# Ruby/Rails: Iterating through ActiveRecord Query Results Using Blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to ruby/rails so please bear with me.

I executed a query and stored it in a @variable located in my controller. In my view I want to output the results as a list, as so:

Controller:

```
def new
  @content = OrientationContent.where("site_id in (?)", [0, session[:site_id]])
end
```

View:

```
<%= @content.each do |c| %>
<ul>
    <li><%= c.content %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

However, my output comes out as so:

```
Check 1
Check 2
Check 3
Check 4
Check 5
Check 6

[#<OrientationContent id: 17, site_id: 0, content: "Check 1", created_at: "2014-12-26 03:46:25",
updated_at: "2014-12-26 03:46:25">, #<OrientationContent id: 18, site_id: 0, content: "Check 
2", created_at: "2014-12-26 03:46:25", updated_at: "2014-12-26 03:46:25">
```

I intentionally cut off the output at the very end since it's a bit long. But it does this for all Check items from 1 to 6.

More so, when I do (1..5) each do |c|

it will output numbers 1 to 5 and at the end it will also output "(1..5)"

My question is how do I keep the first part of the output but not the second half (in my first example, I don't want the records outputted. In my second example, I don't want the "(1..5)" to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fix:

```
<% @content.each do |c| %>
<ul>
    <li><%= c.content %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

`#each` method returns the collection after its completes it iterations. And `<%=` always executed the Ruby code and then print the result, but `<%` executes the code, but never prints. But in your code, you enable `ERB` to print the result of the collection, that's why you are getting what you don't want to get. That's why adapt my *fix* to prevent the printing, but execute only.

Comment: Always the small things, thank you Arup! I will accept answer in 11 minutes!